# Why is volume losing color when hidden behind glass and how do I make it keep its color?

Tags: transparency, color, volumetrics, glass

Everything is done in Cycles.

I created a very simple blue volume and gave it to a cube. I also added a principled shader to make the outside look like shiny glass.

[image: material settings]

The cube on the left has only the volume. The cube on the right has both the volume and principled shader.

[image: first render]

As you can see, the glass causes the volume to lose all color. As it turns out, it is somewhat related to shadow casting, because if I turn off shadow casting by my sun lamp, the color returns to the right cube.

[image: second render]

Why is this happening, and how do I keep the color of the volume without disabling the shadow casting on my light?

[image]

Comment: I don't think there way, as there is a reason why most shaders don't have both "Surface" and "Volume".

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Works fine for me with and without shadow casting enabled.

Comment: @Yohello1 I also tried to create a slighly bigger box which would surround the original one. Original one had only volume shader while the bigger one had only principled glass shader. I had similar results.

Comment: @RobertGützkow I updated the post with a link to the .blend file. Could you try my file?

Comment: Please upload your blend file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add the link to your question. This will preserve the blend file for the future.

Comment: Done. I will remember this feature for the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Volume* max bounces were set to zero in your project. Once you increase them it should give you the intended look.

[image: Light path panel]